# Comparison of user credentials to database

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
for(int i=0;i<numRows;i++)
        {
            String Usernames = rs.getString("Username");
            String Password = rs.getString("Password");
            String getAcc = rs.getString("UserType");
            rs.next();
            if(Usernames.contains(UsernameIn.trim())&&Password.contains(PasswordIn.trim()))
            {
                if(getAcc.trim().equals("admin"))
                {
                    clear();
                    AdminUser.UTypeAdmin(args, UsernameIn, rs, dbTable(), path);
                }
                if(getAcc.trim().equals("standard"))
                {
                    clear();
                    StandardUser.UTypeStandard(args, UsernameIn, rs, dbTable(),path);
                }
            }
            if(!Usernames.contains(UsernameIn.trim())&&!Password.contains(PasswordIn.trim()))
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Credentials Entered");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                clearandreset(args);
            }
        }
```

Ideally, the program would compare the user's input to the resultset and determine if the inputs match. When a correct user enters their credentials, the application runs fine. Eventually the application resets as expected, but when another valid user is entered, the application displays `Invalid Credentials Entered`, thus breaking the application. Has anyone got a solution for this?

Comment: Why are you looping over every row? It would be far more efficient to check if a row exists which matches on username and password.

Comment: Good Question: The simple answer to that is that is the way I have been requested to do it =/

Comment: hopefully all passwords have been salted and hashed before storing and comparing...

Comment: @piet.t This isn't required, as the database sits on a local machine, where PreparedStatements are used

Comment: If your user may choose his/her own password it is strictly required because YOU are not meant to know it!!

Comment: @piet.t you misunderstand, the database contains no sensitive information, so hash/salt isn't a requirement. The PC itself has 3-step authentication anyway

Comment: so a password isn't sensitive information - seems I really don't understand!

Comment: @piet.t re-phrase; The database isn't networked, the PC an only be accessed by a select few and the database itself doesn't contain company-sensitive information, it is essentially a honeypot.

Comment: Ok, if there's no real users' information you might get away with it... otherwise the "selected few" are enough of a scurity-risk to warrant hashing!

Comment: *sigh* I appreciate you're trying to save me a headache but, security-wise, I know what I'm doing.

Comment: is there a reason you use contains instead of equals ?
and why don't you use a simple else in the second part of the condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you should move "invalid credentials" code outside the loop. Otherwise it will work only if credentials matches the first row.

second, check that you are not reusing same result set instance twice

```
for(int i=0;i<numRows;i++)
{
   String Usernames = rs.getString("Username");
   String Password = rs.getString("Password");
   String getAcc = rs.getString("UserType");
   rs.next();
   if(Usernames.contains(UsernameIn.trim())&&Password.contains(PasswordIn.trim()))
   {
      if(getAcc.trim().equals("admin")) {
          clear();
          AdminUser.UTypeAdmin(args, UsernameIn, rs, dbTable(), path);
      }
      if(getAcc.trim().equals("standard")) {
          clear();
          StandardUser.UTypeStandard(args, UsernameIn, rs, dbTable(),path);
      }
   }
}

// We have traversed all rows but not found matching user
System.out.println("Invalid Credentials Entered");
Thread.sleep(2000);
clearandreset(args);
```